# How to pass a jquery var to a jquery function?

Tags: jquery, html

I have an a jquery command like this

```
             if (resultEXTP == "1"){
              $("#generalInfo" ).append("<th><a class='rown'>Extra packing :</a>\
                                  <input  checked id='extrapack' class='css-checkbox' type='checkbox' onClick='extrpk('"+gotid+"')' ></th>");
            } else {
              $("#generalInfo" ).append("<th><a class='rown'>Extra packing :</a>\
                                  <input id='extrapack' class='css-checkbox' type='checkbox' onClick='extrpk('"+gotid+"')' ></th>");             
         }
```

appending a  tag to the generalInfo table.

As you see, this HTML tag has to call a jquery function which is :

```
function extrpk(valorderId){

alert ("i am running " + valorderId);
   // checks if extrapacking requested
        if( $('#extrapack').attr('checked') == true )
        {

            // extrapacking is checked adding to the price
            var classNam = valId;
            //$('.needord').attr('id');
        ....  the rest of the code
```

To pass a jquery var,  gotid to function extrpk to let the function process it.

This function works, if I put the gotid in the `<input checked id=` and then pass the got id as on click (this.id). I mean I can have the alert.

But if I pass it as shown above, the `alert ("i am running ");` won't be alerted.

I don't know what am I doing wrong in the above code?

Comment: use `console.log()` instead of `alert()`

Comment: Why do you use `onclick` handlers when you use jQuery... this is mind-boggling to me.

Comment: try to cnange this `onClick='extrpk('"+gotid+"')'` for this `onClick='extrpk(\'"+gotid+"\')'`

Comment: (\'"+gotid+"\') won't even call the function

Answer (score 0):

Just use standard event handlers. I've significantly cleaned up the code to make it more comprehensible:

```
var $th = $("<th><a class='rown'>Extra packing :</a></th>"),
    $input = $("<input id='extrapack' class='css-checkbox' type='checkbox' />");

$input.on("click", function() {
    extrpk(gotid);
});

if (resultEXTP === "1") {
    $input.prop("checked", true);
}

$th.append($input);
$("#generalInfo").append($th);
```

Comment: I have tried it but it does not show the check box and the th at all

Answer (score 0):

the only answer to my problem that works for me is:

```
              $("#generalInfo" ).append("<th><a class='rown'>Extra packing :</a>\
                              <input  checked id='"+gotid+'<separator>'+idname+"' class='css-checkbox' type='checkbox' onClick='extrpk(this.id)' ></th>");
```

and then split the separator in the extrpk() function then get the tag id and gotid

Thanks everyone for helping me.

Answer (score -1):

Once you have a dynamic control... you will need to call `console.log()` instead of `alert()`

You can see the result using the `F12` key from your browser and going to **console** tab.

Comment: This is completely incorrect--`alert` works fine--and does not answer the question.